# Make/verbs of perception + passive voice

Tags: verbs

> *she makes it **being** connected..*
>
> *I've seen her **being** connected..*
>
> *I heard him **being** punched...*

Are these correct? Should we put **being** or bare infinitive of verb *to be* after verbs of perception in a passive situation?.

And a small question that is related to the topic. Can we say :

> *I've seen **that** she is becoming arrogant*
>
> *I've felt **that** he is changing*

Can we put a complete clause after **that** and verbs of perception?

Comment: **being** or **getting**.  *I saw the house being|getting painted*  or *I watched the team being|getting defeated*.  I saw that the team was being|getting defeated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your examples are actual "passive voice".  That would be more like:

> I see the cake eaten by him.
>
> She heard the bells played by the children.

I'd have to do some research to figure out what exactly your examples would be called (the gerund form of the *to be* verb, maybe), but in the right context, it should be fine:

> I saw her being kissed
>
> She saw me sneaking out of the party.

Your examples don't work, mostly because I don't understand what you are trying to say with "being connected".  You can't normally "connect" a person, and objects normally *are* or *are not* connected, and not "being" in the middle of the process ... but now that I think about it, there are some cases where it's fine:

> My cable service is being connected (the guy from the cable company is here to connect my cable).
>
> Hold on, I'm on the phone being connected to a support representative.

Lastly, "that" is fine in your examples, although it's often unnecessary:

> I see the cake that was eaten by him
>
> She heard the bells that were played by the children.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, what I meant for "being connected" is that she is being connected by someone else to something, it's a passive structure.

Comment: as for the example you gave before, which one is correct, "I saw the cake being eaten by..." or "I saw the cake eaten by..." Is it necessary to put verb to be in the form of gerund or bare infinitive for passive structure after verbs of perception and verb make?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've just noticed mistake there, I meant "she makes it being connected" is odd, you are right, but let's say that she makes something being connected by someone with something, or something like that lol anything that's logically accepted.

Comment: @ChaesarIbrani  Well, again I'm not clear what you want to say.  We wouldn't say "make connected" since there is a perfectly good verb "to connect" that works.  Not trying to be difficult, just trying to give you natural-sounding English examples.

Comment: "Eaten by him" and "being eaten by him" mean different things.  "The cake that was eaten by him" (past) and "the cake that is being eaten by him" (present progressive)

Comment: I think you haven't read the sentence correctly, what I said is, "I saw the cake  eaten by.." Or "I saw the cake being eaten by.." not "the cake" itself as the subject, Does it need verb to be before the past participle in these structures or not?

Comment: @ChaesarIbrani  Yes I know.  The observer is the subject of the verb of perception "to see".  "The cake" is the object of the verb.  I'm trying to break the sentence into manageable pieces.  Whether you need the "to be" verb depends on what you want to say, whether you see him eating the cake **now** or you see the cake that he ate some time in the **past**.

Comment: Although it may sound unnatural, let's put it aside for the sake of example in this question, All I need to understand is that, should we put verb to be in the form of gerund before past participle as passive structure after a clause that contains verbs of perception. For example, "I saw her 'being' kissed by.." or I saw her kissed by..", "I see the car 'being' repaired by.." or "I see the car repaired by...", "I heard my name 'being' repeated by" or "I heard my name repeated by".

Comment: oh okay, according what I learned before, the verb perception indicates the tense of the sentence, such as I saw her doing (it means she is doing it in the past because that I saw her before). It doesn't need to say, "I saw her was doing" because "Saw" already tells the tense, or I am wrong?

Comment: In all your examples, both ways are fine, but they don't necessarily mean the same thing.  "I saw the car repaired by my friend" means I saw the car  which my friend repaired in the past".  "I saw the car being repaired by my friend" means I was *watching* him repair my car.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I mean he he , "I saw her being kissed", is that I was 'watching' her being kissed, so in this example we need verb "to be" right?

Comment: Yes -- and this actually is *passive voice* since she is being kissed (by someone).

Comment: Or I saw him kiss her to be clear, besides that I am still puzzled if it takes verb make, and I am still thinking for the logical example, "she makes the cable being connected by someone to the computer" is all in my head, it means that "she makes someone connecting the cable" even though it sounds unnecessary, but still is it grammatical correct to put verb to be in the form of gerund as the indicative of passive structure there? Similar to verbs of perception but it may have different rules, which I am not sure about, I hope you'd help me with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50566/discussion-between-andrew-and-chaesar-ibrani).